# How to complie lkl/linux on freebsd

Tags: linux, makefile, freebsd

When I complie [lkl/linux](https://github.com/lkl/linux) on freebsd 11.1, I got this error:

```
stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FLnq] [-f format | -l | -r | -s | -x] [-t timefmt] [file|handle ...]
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:984: vmlinux] Error 1
gmake: *** [Makefile:148: /root/linux-master/tools/lkl/lib/lkl.o] Error 2
gmake: Leaving directory '/root/linux-master/tools/lkl
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Is that the first error?   It's complaining that stat does not recognize an option, meaning that you may not have the correct version installed.

Comment: You probably need GNU stat or something like that.